# dynamic table colspan column with 2 static columns

Tags: html, angular

I need some help with dynamic HTML tables.

What I want to achieve is sth. like this :

```
+----------+-------------+--------------+-----+
| Column1  | dynamic col | dynamic col2 | etc |
|          |-------------+--------------+-----+
| rowspan2 | col3 | col4 | col3 | col4  | etc |
+----------+------+------+------+-------+-----+
```

I already tried some things, but my only solution looks like this:

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th rowspan="2">Column1</th>
      <th colspan="2" *ngFor="let col of columns">dynamic col</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="2" *ngFor="let col of columns" >
        <div style="display: inline-block">col3</div>
        <div style="display: inline-block">col4</div>
      </th>
    </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>

   </tbody>
</table>
```

And then trying to build arround the 2 divs... is there a better solution?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Will removing colspan from the second loop work?

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th rowspan="2">Column1</th>
      <th colspan="2" *ngFor="let col of columns">dynamic col</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th *ngFor="let col of columns">
         col{{index}}
      </th>
    </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>

   </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: That 1 would work if I really had an array with the static colnames. Thanks I will do that! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can add more columns by adding the correspondind `td` - 1 in the first row and 2 in the second row

```css
td{
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="2">Column1</td>
    <!-- This is the first dynamic column title -->
    <td colspan="2">dynamic col </td>
    <!-- This is the second dynamic column title -->
    <td colspan="2">dynamic col 2</td>
    <!-- add another td for each new column -->
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <!-- This is the first dynamic column content -->
    <td>aaa</td>
    <td>aaa</td>
    <!-- This is the second dynamic column content -->
    <td>aaa</td>
    <td>aaa</td>
    <!-- Add 2 more td for each column -->
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: uhm, yes I know.
But there is nothing dynamic. What if there is now a 3th dynamicCol ? Then there are not enough "td"

Comment: @tstellfe trying to create columns dynamically not like you suggested.

Comment: I'm not familiar with angular syntax, I guess you can use `ng-repeat` that will create the `td` dynamically

Comment: yes but I need sth arround the 2 bottom <td> to repeat it